# Using retrofit with multiple IP / endpoint

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I'm using retrofit on Android, with success.
But there is a point where I could improve my code, I suppose.

My app is supposed to work on the local network (using 192.168.1.x), but also from the internet (using an alias or a static ip). In a perfect world, I would only use the second one, but in the real world my customers sometimes don't want to activate NAT loopback. 
So now, I have to manage the two ips : if the local ip is not working, I create a new RestAdapter with the global ip, and vice versa.

Right now it's working, but it's slow (I have to wait for the timeout) and not very natural.

Is there any possibility that Retrofit/okhhtp do this job for me, more efficiently ? Like I give retrofit the two endpoints and it tries the two and select the first one to respond ?

Thanks !

EDIT 13.10.2015 : Still no interesting solution. Is retrofit 2.0 helping to resolve this case ?